# MeteorJs show custom version of same app to certain users

Tags: meteor

I'm working on re-developing an existing project written in php. The current company offers its users a 'bespoke solution' - meaning if they want certain parts of the software tailored to their needs.

From speaking to the developer, users are then moved from the 'global' version to their own 'custom' version and any updates that are rolled out to the 'global' version are manually then added to each custom version later.

In meteor, how would one go about replicating this? I'm thinking storing an array in the database with "their custom template names" and then with each page load, check database if any custom templates exist for that user - if yes then load that template else load the default (global) template.

The alternative is to clone the default project for every customer and spin up a separate server for them (Very expensive!!)

How does Facebook etc gradually roll out features - i believe its a similar concept.

Or is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If customization is only done at the level of templates then your proposed approach would work using Meteor's [dynamic templates](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic) capability.

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=myTemplateName }}
```

You would define a helper for the enclosing template that would return `myTemplateName`. That function could execute your logic of looking for a custom template and if not found, defaulting back to a standard one.